# XML parsing using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd

I'm new to xml parsing. I worked with DOM to parse the xml for practice. Now I thought to move some to other xml parsing framework. So I have chosen JAXB parser.For my requirement, I could not create getter setter for all xml tags. Because the xml which I will get is dynamic. So I do not know the tags before hand to create getter/setter.I've referred this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/. Is there any way to do parsing without creating getter and setter.Please make me clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `@XmlAnyElement` and `XmlAnyAttribute` annotations to map the extra content.  If you don't want `get`/`set` methods just add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.

**Customer**

In the class below we map a specific XML attribute and element, and then use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation to map any other elements that may appear, and `@XmlAnyAttribute` to map any other attributes that may appear.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    Map<QName, String> otherAttributes;

    String name;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    List<Object> otherElements;

}
```

**input.xml**

We will unmarshal the following XML document in the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="123" status="good">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <address>
        <street>1 A Street</street>
        <city>Any Town</city>
    </address>
    <phone-number>555-1111</phone-number>
</customer>
```

**Demo**

The following document will unmarshal the XML input, dump all the resulting objects contents to `System.out` and the marshal the object back to XML.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class, Address.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14272453/input.xml");
        Customer customer  = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);


        // Mapped XML Attribute
        System.out.println("customer.id");
        System.out.println("    " + customer.id);

        // Other XML Attributes
        System.out.println("customer.otherAttributes");
        for(Entry<QName, String> entry : customer.otherAttributes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("    " + entry);
        }

        // Mapped XML Element
        System.out.println("customer.name");
        System.out.println("    " + customer.name);

        // Other XML Elements
        System.out.println(customer.otherElements);
        for(Object object : customer.otherElements) {
            System.out.println("    " + object);
        }

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code, note how all the fields are populated with data from the XML document.

```
customer.id
    123
customer.otherAttributes
    status=good
customer.name
    Jane Doe
customer.otherElements
    forum14272453.Address@24f454e4
    [phone-number: null]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="123" status="good">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <address>
        <street>1 A Street</street>
        <city>Any Town</city>
    </address>
    <phone-number>555-1111</phone-number>
</customer>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 1):

For JAXB you should create variables and corresponding getters and setters for all XML tags that you might get dynamically. 
In case you have a tag (that you get dynamically) but you don't have a corresponding mapped variable in the Java class then you will get JAXB Exception.

Hence, you can have a tag defined in JAXB Java Class but comming in request, but the reverse a tag not defined in JAXB Class but comming in XML will give you an exception.

Comment: Yes I know that,Is there any other way to do or any other framework?

Comment: I have also used [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) before but it also has the restriction similar to JAXB.

Comment: A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation by default will not throw an exception for an unexpected attribute/element.  You can specify a custom `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to make this happen if you wish. You can also enable this behaviour by specifying an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller` to enable validation.  If you want the unmapped content you can leverage `@XmlAnyAttribute` and `@XmlAnyElement`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14276830/383861

Comment: Thanks @BlaiseDoughan I did not know that, I have more thing to ask .... I went through your blog post, it dated Dec 21 so is it a new feature or it has been there since a long time, I am using xjc included with Java 6 U 37, so is it included with that version ?

Comment: @AurA - Yes `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` would be included with that version.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be dynamic. unmarshal calls Customer.setElements; marshal calls Customer.getElements

```
@XmlRootElement
class Customer {
    @XmlAnyElement
    public void setElements(List<Element> list) {
        for (Element e : list) {
            String name = e.getNodeName();
            String value = e.getTextContent();
        }
    }

    public List<Element> getElements() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Element e = doc.createElement("e1");
        e.setTextContent("v1");
        list.add(e);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this ,while unmarshalling we need getter of that element,how it is possible?  i tried like                                     public Element getElement(){
        return element;
    } ...getting null as result

Answer (score -1):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), renowned for its JSON processor, also has [XML parsing support](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml), and it does a great job of reflection so that it does the parsing even when there are no getters and setters. Give it a try.